# Check if Windows virtual machine is in use

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop, uipath

In my organization we are using virtual machines that are running UiPath RPA processes. In UiPath Orchestrator it is visible in case a process is running via Orchestrator on the virtual machine.

It is also possible to log into the virtual machines manually, via Remote Desktop Connection. The issue now is that sometimes when an RPA developer is manually logged in to the virtual machine, another user is starting a process from Orchestrator that is using the same machine. This will result in the person manually logged in to the machine being thrown out.

I am trying to come up with a way to detect if a user is already logged in to the machine, and somehow check this before any process is started.

I have experimented and created two batch files that I scheduled via Windows Task Scheduler. The batches create a file in a network drive when a user is unlocking the remote machine, and delete the file when the remote machine is locked.

My issue now is that I would somehow need to check if this file exists before starting any process via Orchestrator. So it cannot be done via UiPath, because this would immediately connect to the machine and throw out the other user.

Anyone who has had some similar problem and solved it?

Comment: The behavior you are trying to manage is controll be UiPath when it initials a job and connects to a robot machine. You may want to reach out to UiPath support/SME to ask this question. I think you are using the same account to login for the user as the robot which results in disconnection. You may want to try using separate windows accounts for the robot and the user and it should work better.

Comment: Yes, but he has only limited licenses. So he does not want another user on the VM, I think. Actually, we had the same issue. To handle this, Is created a node.js tool that create a screenshot every second on the server. Then an addition tool that propagates that image to an web server. And there I was able to see if the server is in use of a human via RDP or a process is running (green icon in taskbar). Maybe this could also be your way. Seeing what is going on on the machine could also be awesome. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple approach
Check who are already logged in

```
Query user /Server:MachineName
```

This will provide a list of users connected to that Host

Now you / Bot, can send out a message ( Msg ) to the respective user to save his work and logout

Both ( query & msg ) are available by default on Windows OS

Code your Bot so this action is performed prior you start your automation

Links

[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/query-user)

[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg)